# Creating and linking a private Umbrella framework

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I am trying to create a private umbrella framework and I am getting some linking issues while linking the umbrella framework with my application.

`SUB` is the sub framework and `Wrapper` is my umbrella framework.

I was able to create the umbrella framework without any issues. But when I try to link this umbrella framework with my test application, it gives the following linker error:

```
ld: file not found: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SUB.framework/Versions/A/SUB for architecture x86_64
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Installation path of `Wrapper.framework` is `@loader_path/../Frameworks`. I want to distribute only the `Wrapper` framework as a private framework and not the `SUB` framework inside it. Any clues what I may be missing?

Comment: Just curious where did you found out how to make a umbrella framework?

Comment: @PhongLe [An Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html) contains some overview of Umbrella framework. And [an Apple mailing list entry](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2006/Aug/msg00637.html) also shows some helpful information.